# aptanaで作ったRuby on Rails環境で error: Invalid path ':ruby' と表示される

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aptana

WindowsにaptanaでRuby on Railsアプリを開発できる環境を整えたのですが、何かしらコマンドを打つ度に

> error: Invalid path ':ruby'

と表示されます。なんかパッと見問題なく動いているようなんで逆に怖いです。これなんですか？

Comment: Aptanaでどのようなコマンドを入力するとそのエラーメッセージが出るのでしょうか？

Comment: Aptanaを使っていないのでどっちみちわからないかもしれませんが、ちょっと情報が少なすぎる気がします。スクリーンショットや再現手順等、もっと詳しい情報を追記すると回答が付くかもしれません。